# C# Active Directory - Read out Email NullReferencesException

Tags: c#, .net, windows, exception, active-directory

I'm trying to get the e-mail adresses of all user's in our company domain.
99% work but sometimes there is y NullReferenceException in my Output.

Code:

```
string dom = "mydomain";

System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry entry = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + dom); //domain, user, password
System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher ds = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(entry);

ds.Filter = ("(objectClass=User)");
int count = 1;

foreach (System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult resEnt in ds.FindAll())
{
    try
    {
        System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry de = resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry(); 
        String email = de.Properties["mail"].Value.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't actually see a question in your post. What is your question?

Comment: if someone know why there is sometime a nullreference exception on line `code`String email = de.Properties["mail"].Value.ToString();`code`

Comment: //edit: i get 377 email adresses but in our domain there are 383... if i look in the log of my application there are 6 nullpointers.. Does anybody know where this code won't work for this 6 user's?

Comment: Have you tried actually looking at those users with a tool like [AD Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb795532.aspx) and checking their properties to make sure they actually have a mail property just like the others?

Comment: sorry got an 'brainlag' you'r right theres no email adress at some users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a `NullReferenceException` in the line

```
String email = de.Properties["mail"].Value.ToString();
```

If in the `Properties["mail"]` returns a `null` value or its `Value` property is `null`, then the attempt to call `ToString()` will lead to an exception.

This will help in this case (C# 6 syntax)

```
String email = de.Properties["mail"]?.Value?.ToString();
```

or

```
String email = null;
if (de.Properties["mail"] != null && de.Properties["mail"].Value != null)
{
    email = de.Properties["mail"].Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: @Flow - you are welcome. Please mark the post as "answer" if it has solved your problem.